# vim command line editting

Tags: vim, vi

is there a way to use vim/vi in the vim command line? Sometimes I write a long
command in vim such as:

```
:!./script /home/user/pet --flag=1
```

and I want to change for instance "user" by "other". What I usually do is to
navigate the command line with right arrow which is time consuming and even more
when I want to go to the beginning of the line. I would like to have something 
like "0" to go there or w/b to move by words. Or use j/k to go to the next/previous
command.

Thanks.

Comment: What is your shell?  Most have shortcuts for those things, like these in Bash: http://www.ice2o.com/bash_quick_ref.html

Comment: (It's just a matter of learning a different set of keystrokes)

Comment: I am using the zsh but what I want is to edit a command in the vim command line

Comment: Ohhh.. I misunderstood.  Sounds like what you want is `q:`, the cmdline-window

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/7186880/329063.

Answer (score 6):

```
:h cedit
```

- in command line, type `ctrl-F`(default) to enter command window.
- or in normal mode type `q:`

(for search, type `q/`)

Answer (score 4):

Vim has a feature called the "commandline window". You can enter it with Control-F by default when you're already on the commandline, or `q:` from normal mode, edit the commandline using vim commands, and press enter to execute. It also contains your command history so that you can yank previous commands if you like. See `:help cmdline-window` for more information.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware how you can use Vim commands to edit a command directly on the command line, but if you enter the command window `q:` you get can use regular Vim editing to edit commands.

From there you can execute commands by hitting `<CR>` or use `Ctrl-C` to copy the command to the regular command line.

Comment: When downvoting please leave a comment. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you run set -o vi you will have vim capabilities in your command line. Just put 'set -o vi' in your .bashrc file or equivalent to have it by default.